# Django: Models: How can I make the app_label appear in all caps?

Tags: django-models, django-admin, metamodel

1. If I manually set my app_label, is there a way to set it to all caps? I am using an acronym for the app name and is a little confusing to not have it in all caps.
2. If I set the app_label on a new project, were I have no users or data, what kind of issues should I look when setting up user permissions and database tables?